# CSOM get list items, return simple data structure

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model

If we take this code example, we can see we need to call a lot of methods to get to our results (`.getEnumerator()`, `.get_current()`, `.get_title()`, `.get_title()`)

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function retrieveAllListProperties() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

    clientContext.load(collList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    var listInfo = '';

    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' Created: ' + oList.get_created().toString() + '\n';
    }
    alert(listInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Is there any built in method will will return the results in the form of a simple data structure, e.g. an array of objects, each object representing a list item, e.g:

```
[
    {ID:1, Title:"value", Author:"value" ...},
    {ID:2, Title:"value", Author:"value" ...},
    {ID:3, Title:"value", Author:"value" ...}
    ...
]
```

Or if I could access the original JSON returned from `_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery` as that has a clean enough structure.

My goal is to pass on a clean data structure to a templating engine like doT.js or Handlebars.js, without the need to loop through and manually build a new data structure using the methods outlined above. Seems like an unnecessary step when a decent structure is right there in the JSON response.

Answer (score 10):

There is no built in method in [SharePoint 2010 JavaScript Object Model (JSOM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh372944%28v=office.14%29.aspx) that allow to return list items in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format, but it could be accomplished with an *Object to JSON serializer*

### JSON.stringify

[JSON stringifier](http://www.json.org/js.html) function is intended for convering JavaScript data structures into JSON text.

### How it works

Let's see how to retrieve task item properties from *Tasks* list

```
function loadTasks()
{
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Tasks");
        var viewXml = '<View><RowLimit>1200</RowLimit></View>';
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml(viewXml);
        var items = list.getItems(query);
        context.load(items,"Include(Title,AssignedTo,Status,Priority)");
        context.add_requestSucceeded(onLoaded);
        context.add_requestFailed(onFailure);
        context.executeQueryAsync();
        function onLoaded() {
            var tasksEntries = [];
            var itemsCount = items.get_count();
            for (i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                var item = items.itemAt(i);
                var taskEntry = JSON.stringify(item.get_fieldValues());
                tasksEntries.push(taskEntry);
            }
        }
        function onFailure() {

        }
}
```

> Note:
>
> a)Items properties that should be initialized are explicitly specified
>   using `"Include(Title,AssignedTo,Status,Priority)"`
>
> b)for retrieving field properties(name/value) `SP.ListItem`
>   `get_fieldValues` is used
>
> c)finally JSON.stringify is used to convert field properties object to
>   JSON

Result for tasksEntries:

```
[
  {"Title":"Task 1","AssignedTo":{"$b_1":"Developer","$M_1":1},"Status":"Not Started","Priority":"(2) Normal"},
  {"Title":"Task 2","AssignedTo":{"$b_1":"Developer","$M_1":1},"Status":"In Progress","Priority":"(3) Low"}
  {"Title":"Task 3","AssignedTo": {"$b_1":"Developer","$M_1":1},"Status":"Completed","Priority":"(2) Normal"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always construct your own DVWP to return your desired JSON for use in a templating engine.  I've been playing around with this for a couple days and really starting to see it's potential. http://www.metaengine.com/2012/12/Returning-JSON-from-the-SharePoint-DVWP-aka-poor-mans-GetSiteData

Server does the work fetching the data and you can set it up to supply you with whatever inforamtion you need for your templates.

Comment: Very cool approach!

Comment: I used a similar technique a couple of years ago, converting data views to JSON with XSL, but I'd rather keep the dynamic query ability rather than have to set up a data view each time

Comment: link no longer works.